# android ant compile failing

Tags: android, apache, ant, compiler-errors

I'm compiling android project through apache ant. after android update project command. I put ant release in my root directory of the project. It says

"C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\main_rules.xml:384: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details."

1. Where do i see compiler output ?
2. What kind of error this should be because same project I can build through eclipse and sign application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where do i see compiler output ?

In theory, it will be in your Command Prompt window, where you ran the `ant release` command, and above where you see the "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\main_rules.xml:384: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.".

> What kind of error this should be because same project I can build through eclipse and sign application?

That is impossible to answer in the abstract, sorry.

Comment: I found the problem. I think you can edit your answer. I will mark it as correct answer. Problem was with lib. I added all external lib likes admob sdk in "lib" folder. Instead it should go in "libs" folder. It works fine in eclipse even we use name lib. But for ant we need it to be in libs folder.

Comment: @Umakant Patil: Yes, Ant needs JARs to be in `libs/`. That is why I recommend that people create and use `libs/` even with Eclipse, to make it easier to transition to command-line builds in the future (e.g., for continuous integration).

Comment: @CommonsWare - I found this to be necessary as well. It means every project that uses  a jar needs to have its own copy. Is there no way of overriding this in the build.properties to avoid wasting disk space? I've tried setting jar.libs.absolute.dir etc all to no avail - it keeps complaining about missing libs directory

Comment: @NickT: With hard drives on developer machines in the multi-hundred-GB range, worrying about the space for JAR files suitable for use on mobile devices would seem to be a waste of effort. That being said, you can always try a symlink (if you're on OS X or Linux at least).

Comment: @CommonsWare : Thanks - I'll live with it, I shouldn't be so churlish I guess. It just goes against the grain that's all. Anyway I could always write my own build.xml which didn't refer to main rules if I felt that strongly ( and had a spare week or so!)